# RightFax 10.5 java integration issue

Tags: rightfax

I am trying to do some POC on Rightfax integration with JAVA API. Installed all required components in Rightfax Server (JAVA/XML API) and configured the IIS (took care while installing the rightfax server) while running the sample java program getting following message

```
here are the details of the output in debug mode

<XML_FAX_SUBMIT java="1" stylesheet="XML_FAX_SUBMIT.xslt" xmlns="x-schema:XML_FAX_SUBMIT.xdr">
<INCLUDE_BEG>xml.beg</INCLUDE_BEG>
    <SENDER>
        <RF_USER>ADMINISTRATOR</RF_USER>
    </SENDER>
    <DESTINATIONS>
        <FAX>
            <TO_FAXNUM>555-7777</TO_FAXNUM>
        </FAX>
    </DESTINATIONS>
    <BODY>
How about some body text.
Line 2
Line 3
    </BODY>
<INCLUDE_END>xml.end</INCLUDE_END>
</XML_FAX_SUBMIT>

Initiating Connection to: http://<name>/rfxml/rfwebcon.dll
RETURN XML:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XML_FAX_SUBMIT_REPLY>
    <FAX unique_id="unknown">
        <STATUS_CODE>-1</STATUS_CODE>
        <STATUS_MSG>Failed to load XML into DOM tree.</STATUS_MSG>
    </FAX>
</XML_FAX_SUBMIT_REPLY>
Message Successfully Transported
ID: unknown
`Code`: -1
**Msg: Failed to load XML into DOM tree.**
Ended


could anyone help me if you come across this type of issue or any configuration is missing at Fax Server or IIS side.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create a outbound fax object
RFaxSubmit faxSubmit= new RFaxSubmit();
//set XMLNS and make sure you have XML_FAX_SUBMIT_schema.xml in your classpath.
faxSubmit.m_FaxDocument.setXMLNS("classpath:XML_FAX_SUBMIT_schema.xml");
```

This file must be available on your RightFax server, @ this location \RightFax\Production\xml\schemas\XML_FAX_SUBMIT_schema.xml download this file or ask server support and add it in your classpath.